# How to change Android EditText keyboard color?

Tags: android, android-edittext, uitextfield

In iOS `TextField` has a property called `Appeareance` can have a `Dark` value. It will change the **KEYBOARD** color, (not the textfield itsels) But in Android I do not find the appropriate one for [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), to change keyboard color to dark, or black.

Comment: Reasonable question, google search did not help me. Maybe two platform manage keyborad coloring differently?

Comment: Talking not about the color of the text, but color of the keyboard.

Comment: There is no such a feature in Android. The stock Google keyboard has different themes, but they can only be changed via the Keyboard app itself, rather than programmatically.

Comment: But it distroy the look and feel of the app. I doubt, it is not doable.

Comment: I think the only way is creating something like a fragment popping up from bottom. then you disable the keyboard from showing and you use this fragment as a keyboard (you have to create a full keyboard feature, with caps, numbers exc). I don't know if you got what i wanna say but this might work

Comment: There is no way to do this. The keyboard is completely separate from your app and users can replace the system keyboard with any third party one from the Play Store if they want to.

Comment: Btw in android you can't (without root priviledge) because since keyboard is not default but is another application, you are not able to override another app's configuration

Comment: Understood, but too much work to do it. Cant image Android is still so outdated.

Comment: honestly it's only your opinion. having the keyboard on a separated app is not outdated. it's better(in my opinion)! because you can use the keyboard you like and the style you want. Imagine if I would not like your keyboard style. why should I be forced to use it if I found a style I like more?

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley in iOS u can make / use your own "custom keyboard", but if just want offer a "dark standard" keyboard and not the "light" in your app, u need just changing a flag and that is all.

Comment: Yes but in Android custom keyboards have tons of custom behaviours. you can do everything you want. btw also on Android you can change the style with one click. but we are going out of topic, it's not a discussion about which system is better since it's only opinion based. whoever like to have full customizing power will prefer Android and others will prefer IOS/Windows phone. The simple answer for you is "you can't without root acces because you can't access another application from your"

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley could you post Answer how to change style with **one click**, this is what I am asking. As I told I have an `EditText` specified in a layout xml file.

Comment: you can do it from the keyboard app. not from your app (for example swiftkey can style the layout with one click). but this is due to the keyboard app, not from your. the user must decide to change the style and unfortunatly you can't

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no single "the keyboard" in Android. Android supports replaceable input method editors (a.k.a., soft keyboards). These are published by apps, including both pre-installed apps and apps installed by users. Anyone can write one of these.

AFAIK, there is nothing in the input method editor protocol that allows the editor to know anything about the color scheme of the app that happened to cause that editor to appear. But, even if the protocol included this information, the developer of the input method editor could choose to ignore it.

And, even if the developer of the input method editor knew about the general theme (light vs. dark) and chose to implement something for it, you still might not like what the developer chooses. After all, there is no universal definition of what a "light" or "dark" theme should look like. The input method editor developer might choose a deep purple color for "dark", and you went with dark brown.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: you can't.

In Android the keyboard is not (only) a native feature. You can chose wether showing it or not and which keyboard to show.

But since it's another application, you can't access it directly, the only tasks you can do are opening the app with intent.

[here you can find the official doc about it](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but note the following

1. The keyboard is a different application
2. The text appearance properties can be easily modified from the xml file

look at the example code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/simple_list_item"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:allowUndo="false"
    android:text="Sample Still Testing"
    android:textColor="#003325" />
```

Comment: The question is about changing the color of Android keyboard. But your answer tells how to modify TextView appearance. Two completely different things.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I just checked again and I found that an edit was made after I tried to answer the question: `In iOS TextField has a property called Appeareance can have a Dark value. But in Android I do not find the appropriate one for EditText, to change keyboard color to dark, or black.`. OP clarified but I didn't update my answer or remove it accordingly. I'd keep it here though, someone interested in knowing how appearance properties can be changed might just stumble on this.