# How can I change the color of enter key in the keyboard of a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I want to change the color of enter key in the keyboard of a flutter app. How can I achieve this?
with the default keyboard or with a custom keyboard.

I am using

```
TextFormField(keyboardType:TextInputType.text,maxLines:1)
```

as the widget here

Comment: According to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704428/how-to-change-android-edittext-keyboard-color, you have no control over the keyboard.

In Android the keyboard is a different App and you can not access its theming like that. As far as I am aware, you can only change which action button is shown via the `textInputAction` property and the type of the keyboard (text or number, etc.).

Comment: it is not part of your UI, so it cant be done, but you can develop you own KeyBoard to achieve what you are looking for